# Updating existing fields with data from another field in the same row and data from another table - SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, inner-join

I have a table TABLE1 that goes like this (just a few records):

| fecha1 | hora1 | fecha2 | hora2 | codigo1 | codigo2 | codigo3 | codigo4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-12 | 1900-01-01 07:00:00.000 | 2022-08-13 | 1900-01-01 01:18:00.000 | 612 | 1837520919 | LineaA_Loria_Turn12 | 1500 |
| 2022-08-12 | 1900-01-01 07:00:00.000 | 2022-08-13 | 1900-01-01 01:18:00.000 | 612 | 1812527159 | LineaD_Callao_Turn9 | 750 |
| 2022-08-12 | 1900-01-01 07:00:00.000 | 2022-08-13 | 1900-01-01 01:18:00.000 | 612 | 1838404812 | LineaE_Virreyes_Turn5 | 750 |
| 2022-08-12 | 1900-01-01 07:00:00.000 | 2022-08-13 | 1900-01-01 01:18:00.000 | 612 | 1843766323 | LineaC_Constitucion_Turn15 | 750 |
| 2022-08-01 | 1900-01-01 19:36:00.000 | 2022-08-02 | 1900-01-01 01:01:00.000 | 612 | 1732054697 | LineaC_Retiro_Turn11 | 1500 |
| 2022-08-01 | 1900-01-01 19:37:00.000 | 2022-08-02 | 1900-01-01 01:01:00.000 | 612 | 1835202082 | LineaH_Hospitales_Turn1 | 3000 |
| 2022-08-01 | 1900-01-01 19:37:00.000 | 2022-08-02 | 1900-01-01 01:01:00.000 | 612 | 1828702502 | LineaC_Independencia_Turn6 | 1500 |

I need to split the `codigo3` field from TABLE1 so one part will replace `codigo1` value and another part will replace `codigo4` value, as in this example:

`LineaC_Retiro_Turn11` will be split into `LineaC` and `Retiro` (the `Turn11` part here is of no use) and should modify its own row from this:

| fecha1 | hora1 | fecha2 | hora2 | codigo1 | codigo2 | codigo3 | codigo4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 | 1900-01-01 19:37:00.000 | 2022-08-02 | 1900-01-01 01:01:00.000 | 612 | 1828702502 | LineaC_Retiro_Turn11 | 1500 |

to this:

| fecha1 | hora1 | fecha2 | hora2 | codigo1 | codigo2 | codigo3 | codigo4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 | 1900-01-01 19:37:00.000 | 2022-08-02 | 1900-01-01 01:01:00.000 | LineaC | 1828702502 | LineaC_Retiro_Turn11 | Retiro |

But I have another table, TABLE2, that links the value `LineaC` (in this example) with a numerical code, `444`, and I want also to replace that `LineaC` with that code, if possible at the same time I am performing the UPDATE. Every value `Linea%` has its own numeric code, and there are just a few codes. So this example should end up like this:

| fecha1 | hora1 | fecha2 | hora2 | codigo1 | codigo2 | codigo3 | codigo4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 | 1900-01-01 19:37:00.000 | 2022-08-02 | 1900-01-01 01:01:00.000 | 444 | 1828702502 | LineaC_Retiro_Turn11 | Retiro |

TABLE1 does not have an ID or a PK. `codigo2`, which could seem to be one, repeats itself alongside TABLE1 n times; `codigo1` is always the same value; and `codigo4` is a fare that also repeats itself in TABLE1 with no pattern (it's just a fare), so there is no way to tell which row must be updated unless you take all fields altogether, and I cannot assure that even that would work (mostly because the hour fields `hora1` and `hora2` don't have the seconds, or they are always '00'), so I have to rely on the row number to make those changes, or alter the table to add a sequence as an ID on a new field.

In either case, with or without an ID field, how do I make the update in order to get TABLE1 `codigo1` replaced with the numeric value from TABLE2 and the middle string from TABLE1 `codigo3` replacing TABLE1 `codigo4`?

I'm splitting using the following query:

```
SELECT Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(codigo3), '_', '.'), 1)
    ) AS part1,
    Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(x.codigo3), '_', '.'), 2)
    ) AS part2
FROM TABLE1
```

But it does not return just one row but all the existing rows in TABLE1, so I need to select just the "codigo3" value corresponding to the same row I want to update.

Comment: Maybe the update from TABLE2, being so few records matching the possible values of "codigo3" field from TABLE1 could be listed on a CASE / WHEN / ELSE / END structure? So it could avoid using TABLE2... Just a thought on this

Comment: Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: A [mre] includes: cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK.

Comment: What version of SQL Server please?

Comment: @philipxy you are absolutely right. Fact is that I had neither as a bad query nor a function to show. I will try to follow your kind advise whenever I need to ask again. Horaciux has solved my problem and I have just to make few changes to make it work as I desired, so I consider it solved. Thank you all for your kind help

Comment: @ChrisSchaller is in the title: SQL Server 2019, I should have written it in the main text also, shouldn't I?

Comment: Your post is here forever to help others (if it isn't deleted by people thinking it is not a positive contribution to the site as a collection of good Q&A). Please consider editing to improve it as best you can, along the lines of the issue you feel the accepted answer addressed.

Comment: Yes, clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. Use a tag for a version of software. Then it is not needed in the post body. Your original post should have had that, along with the rest of a [mre]. PS You can learn more about the site googling Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. (Use the google 'site:' facility.)

Comment: @philipxy I will edit it with the answer provided by Horaciux and the modifications I made to make it work the way I desired it to do so. Also will add the version to the post, and will read about the site as suggested. I'm sorry if I did not meet all the rules, I'm new to SQL Server and English is not my mother language, so I'm facing two challenges: trying to solve SQL problems and at the same time trying to communicate as good as possible a problem so I can get appropriate help. Being new to SQL Server also let me many times empty of ideas though I'm learning all the time

Comment: Not sure what you intend when editing but--Please do not put answers into question posts. Re editing "along the lines of the issue you feel the accepted answer addressed" I mean, more or less, edit if possible to ask only the question that the answer answers. Your post isn't clear or focused so I really don't know whether you think it adequately addresses any particular bug(s) and/or  just the overall goal or part(s) of it. (Pin down question posts to "1 specific researched non-duplicate question"!) Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a CTE `split` to calculate the `part1` and `new_codigo4` values. The CTE is then joined with `TABLE1` and `TABLE2` to update the `codigo1` and `codigo4` fields in `TABLE1`.

```
-- Create TABLE1
drop table if exists table1;


CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (
    fecha1 DATE,
    hora1 DATETIME,
    fecha2 DATE,
    hora2 DATETIME,
    codigo1 VARCHAR(50),
    codigo2 BIGINT,
    codigo3 VARCHAR(50),
    codigo4 VARCHAR(50)
);

drop table if exists table2;

-- Create TABLE2
CREATE TABLE TABLE2 (
    linea VARCHAR(10),
    numeric_code INT
);


-- Insert sample data into TABLE1
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (fecha1, hora1, fecha2, hora2, codigo1, codigo2, codigo3, codigo4)
VALUES
('2022-08-12', '1900-01-01 07:00:00.000', '2022-08-13', '1900-01-01 01:18:00.000', '612', '1837520919', 'LineaA_Loria_Turn12', '1500'),
('2022-08-12', '1900-01-01 07:00:00.000', '2022-08-13', '1900-01-01 01:18:00.000', '612', '1812527159', 'LineaD_Callao_Turn9', '750'),
('2022-08-12', '1900-01-01 07:00:00.000', '2022-08-13', '1900-01-01 01:18:00.000', '612', '1838404812', 'LineaE_Virreyes_Turn5', '750'),
('2022-08-12', '1900-01-01 07:00:00.000', '2022-08-13', '1900-01-01 01:18:00.000', '612', '1843766323', 'LineaC_Constitucion_Turn15', '750'),
('2022-08-01', '1900-01-01 19:36:00.000', '2022-08-02', '1900-01-01 01:01:00.000', '612', '1732054697', 'LineaC_Retiro_Turn11', '1500'),
('2022-08-01', '1900-01-01 19:37:00.000', '2022-08-02', '1900-01-01 01:01:00.000', '612', '1835202082', 'LineaH_Hospitales_Turn1', '3000'),
('2022-08-01', '1900-01-01 19:37:00.000', '2022-08-02', '1900-01-01 01:01:00.000', '612', '1828702502', 'LineaC_Independencia_Turn6', '1500');

-- Insert sample data into TABLE2
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (linea, numeric_code)
VALUES
('LineaA', 111),
('LineaB', 222),
('LineaC', 444),
('LineaD', 333),
('LineaE', 555),
('LineaH', 666);



WITH split AS (
    SELECT *,
           LEFT(codigo3, CHARINDEX('_', codigo3) - 1) AS part1,
           SUBSTRING(codigo3, CHARINDEX('_', codigo3) + 1, CHARINDEX('_', STUFF(codigo3, CHARINDEX('_', codigo3), 1, ' ')) - CHARINDEX('_', codigo3) - 1) AS new_codigo4
    FROM TABLE1
)
UPDATE t1
SET t1.codigo1 = t2.numeric_code,
    t1.codigo4 = split.new_codigo4
FROM TABLE1 t1
JOIN split ON t1.codigo2 = split.codigo2
JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t2.linea = split.part1;


select * from table1
```

| fecha1 | hora1 | fecha2 | hora2 | codigo1 | codigo2 | codigo3 | codigo4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-12 | 1900-01-01 07:00:00.000 | 2022-08-13 | 1900-01-01 01:18:00.000 | 111 | 1837520919 | LineaA_Loria_Turn12 | Loria |
| 2022-08-12 | 1900-01-01 07:00:00.000 | 2022-08-13 | 1900-01-01 01:18:00.000 | 333 | 1812527159 | LineaD_Callao_Turn9 | Callao |
| 2022-08-12 | 1900-01-01 07:00:00.000 | 2022-08-13 | 1900-01-01 01:18:00.000 | 555 | 1838404812 | LineaE_Virreyes_Turn5 | Virreyes |
| 2022-08-12 | 1900-01-01 07:00:00.000 | 2022-08-13 | 1900-01-01 01:18:00.000 | 444 | 1843766323 | LineaC_Constitucion_Turn15 | Constitucion |
| 2022-08-01 | 1900-01-01 19:36:00.000 | 2022-08-02 | 1900-01-01 01:01:00.000 | 444 | 1732054697 | LineaC_Retiro_Turn11 | Retiro |
| 2022-08-01 | 1900-01-01 19:37:00.000 | 2022-08-02 | 1900-01-01 01:01:00.000 | 666 | 1835202082 | LineaH_Hospitales_Turn1 | Hospitales |
| 2022-08-01 | 1900-01-01 19:37:00.000 | 2022-08-02 | 1900-01-01 01:01:00.000 | 444 | 1828702502 | LineaC_Independencia_Turn6 | Independencia |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BNXF_I1D)

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation in addition to working code.

Comment: @Horaciux thank you for your help. The SELECT subquery works Ok, and the UPDATE would work ok also but sadly the codigo2 field as I stated before is not a unique value throughout the table, but based on your query I'll alter the table by adding a column with a unique value (a sequence) and that will do the trick.

Comment: @FatsGordon Awesome, I'm glad it helped set you on the right track to solve it.
Make a few amendments to your question, copy all DDL, and DML I created from scratch but with the correct schema, and add your query attempts and negative result.

Comment: @FatsGordon & Horaciux As I said in a comment on the question, it really is not helpful to just dump code that doesn't do what you expect, let alone multiple cases of such code, & a goal (as if you were trying to show effort); either ask about a minimal bad query whose behaviour you don't understand but researched or else show relevant working parts & ask about getting stuck getting to a goal. PS Is 7 rows really minimal representative/illustrative data?

Comment: @philipxy I'm familiarized with the dataset (Buenos Aires subway trips) and instantly understand the need. I might not be objective in this case.

Comment: Well I speak for me, I have to disagree here: Horaciux not only understood what the problem was but he helped me a lot by showing me one possible way to solve it (and I did solve it thanks to Horaciux), and you kept telling me I wasn't clear at all ("Your post isn't clear or focused"), while Horaciux got it completely right. Told you I'm new to SQL Server and almost new to SO, so I could be posting the wrong way and I apologized about that, but (to me) your directions are confusing. I'm 60 yo and trying to do things the best I can. I'm still working and learning and asking for help when needed

Comment: @FatsGordon & Horaciux My comments are about what makes a good question (& avoids needless duplicate questions). What someone might be able to wring out of a question anyway is a separate issue. I'm done.